SVG Image doesn't show up when I use app:srcCompat but works fine when I use android:src
I downloaded and Added an SVG file to my Project's Drawable Directory. When I used it in my Layout with app:srcCompat, the Image doesn't get displayed. I even added the VectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true to the app build.gradle file but still nothing.
However the Image does show up when I use android:src. Is this the right way of displaying an SVG Vector Asset in my Layout(s) and/or even png Images? I've read posts where people complain their Images blurring when using the android:src Attribute.
Below is the Image File:
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="960"
    android:viewportHeight="960">
  <path
      android:pathData="M280,840q-33,0 -56.5,-23.5T200,760v-520h-40v-80h200v-40h240v40h200v80h-40v520q0,33 -23.5,56.5T680,840L280,840ZM680,240L280,240v520h400v-520ZM360,680h80v-360h-80v360ZM520,680h80v-360h-80v360ZM280,240v520,-520Z"
      android:fillColor="#BD4C31"/>
</vector>

My Layout File:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">
    
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/task_name_new_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/task_name_placeholder"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.12"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/task_done_checkbox_new"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/task_done_cb_txt"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/task_name_new_tv"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/task_name_new_tv" />

        **<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/delete_button_imgv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="Delete Image"
            android:src="@drawable/delete_icon"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />**

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.86" />
        
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>



Image is displaying fine with app:srcCompat. I am using your code and icon.
please check your spellings it should be app:srcCompat

I tried. Image is still not showing up when using srcCompat. My Layout is being displayed in a Fragment so not sure if that has something to do with it.

yes maybe. can you please upload your full xml code? because the provided code is working for me. Can you please try running the app with srcCompat to confirm if its working in compiled apk or not
